# After $IE.Quit(), the Internet Explorer still exists in Task manager

Tags: powershell

My case happens when I run $IE.quit() already, but internet explorer still exists in the task manager.

- if I run the quit function at "quit IE 1" there, the Internet Explorer will close/end (not exits in Task Manager),
- but when I run it at "quit IE 2" there, the IE not end (still exist in Task Manager)
- if run with `$IE.Visible = $true` it has no such problem.
- Environment: Windows Server 2016, PowerShell v5.1

1. May I know what may cause this?
2. May I know after the "confirm page loaded", what happened to `$IE`? And possibly cause IE not to quit.
3. Or how I can trace this kind of problem?

I do try to run this without `try`/`catch`, but the same thing happens. I try to put `$IE = null`, but the same, while, the `$IE.Quit()` description as to force the end of IE, suppose no wonder what is running on the IE. It will end the task.

Here is the PowerShell script:

```
$looping = 10
timenowhms = (Get-Date -f HH:mm:ss)
try {
    $Url = "http://localhost:8080/commandcenter/checking.aspx"
    $IE = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application
    $IE.Height = 700
    $IE.Width = 750
    $IE.Top = 10
    $IE.Left = 10
    $IE.Visible = $false; # can turn on for testing purpose
    $IE.Navigate2($url);
    $IEPID = [IntPtr]::Zero
    [Win32Api]::GetWindowThreadProcessId($IE.HWND, [ref]$IEPID);
    # quit IE 1
    $IE.Quit();
} catch {
    $timenowhms = (Get-Date -f HH:mm:ss);
    echo "$td_date $timenowhms       Open website failed";
    if ((Get-Process -Name "iexplore*" | ? {$_.Id -eq $IEPID} | measure).Count -eq 1) {
        Stop-Process -Id $IEPID -force
    };
    exit 1
}
# confirm page loaded
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {
    if ($looping -eq 0) {
        $timenowhms = (Get-Date -f HH:mm:ss);
        echo "$td_date $timenowhms       Timeout, page not show";
        if ((Get-Process -Name "iexplore*" | ? {$_.Id -eq $IEPID} | measure).Count -eq 1) {
            Stop-Process -Id $IEPID -Force
        };
        exit 1
    } else {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2500;
        $looping--;
    }
}
# quit IE 2
# $IE.Quit();
exit
```

Comment: i could be off, but isn't it `$IE.close()`

Comment: My side get error for this:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $IE.close()
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'close'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $IE.close()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: I just tried, and mine quits with `$IE.quit()` maybe it's still calculating before quitting, the .quit() method may just be a suggestion to it, and not a kill command. IF it is the only internet explorer open, you could just force it with `get-process -name 'iexplore' | stop-process -force` but this will close all instances

Comment: Yes right away, it didn't close, but after a second i got it to quit with a wait on checking if it exists, you could actually just get a list of current open iexplore commands, then run this, get a new list, and kill any differences

Comment: Want to note, killing the differences doesn't fully work, as some more iexplorer windows will "open" as they are a sub process. But something worth looking into.

Comment: yes. i was get the PID and kill it.
but just wondering why the $IE.quit not end task the IE. and i do have $ie.Busy to wait the IE finish process, so suppose not IE still getting in rendering right?

Comment: Maybe it's the website or something is taking forever, or locking it open, and it's "asking" you to quit...  anyhow, found this. might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642883/how-to-properly-close-internet-explorer-when-launched-from-powershell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly close Internet Explorer when launched from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642883/how-to-properly-close-internet-explorer-when-launched-from-powershell)

Comment: is a good reference, but i just try all that
$_.quit(), garbage thing. but same. 
now the only success way i do is use IE PID to close IE after i get the info. then the script will continue to run and exit.

Comment: The 'garbage thing' DOES work. I suspect that by earlier tries you still have a lot of IE Com objects lurking in the background that were not released before. Try with a clean system (i.e. first kill all iexplore processes) and restart your PowerShell instance.

Comment: Try this: [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($IE) | Out-Null

Comment: i do try also. but is same.

Comment: For Theo:
i suspect the same thing. but i do that most time, start with clean also same result.(even i try after restart the server)
and $IE.quit suppose force those related IE close right? (like kill )
if it is something running, and IE.quit not force to close it. then how i going to know when the IE is invisible?
cause i try with ```visible=true``` it not happen this.